# Cashable, Depositable Or Redeemable On Invoice?

Tags: cash, deposits, receipt, check

I will be issuing invoices to my customer very soon.  I don't know whether I will be cashing or depositing the cheque sent in for payment.  What is the best way to communiate this to my customers?  Are any of these acceptable to print on my invoice?

**1. Cashable At (date)**

**2. Depositable At (date)**

**3. Redeemable At (date)**

Not sure but "Redeemable At" makes more sense as it implies both 1 and 2?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better asked at [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: None of these. "Payment due in full 30 days after invoice date." It's not their concern how you plan to handle the check. In fact, it makes no difference, when I send you a check for your fine product/service, it's simply made payable to you.

Comment: @Joe, why isn't it an answer?

Comment: After Chad's observation, i.e. this isn't a question, I decided to reply, but not answer.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you want to mention the date on which the invoice is good for payment. If that is the case, the most appropriate is 3. Reedemable. 2. Depositable does not make much of a sense. And Reedemable includes Cashable.